Using invoice.created to report metered usage
I want to report usage to Stripe, using their meter events API. Instead of applying a CRON job that runs every hour or every day, I was thinking to use the invoice.created webhook event to trigger a function that will report usage to stripe by sending a meter event.
Is it safe/reliable to do? Docs say there is a gap of about an hour between invoice creation and invoice finalization. Need suggestions. Thanks.

Grace period is supported on usage-based billing. During this one-hour grace period, you can continue to report usage for the previous period. When the invoice finalises, we update it to reflect the latest quantity for its billing period
